# Settin general defaults for named arguments in python

Tags: python

I have the following problem:
I have to set some values for special entities (points, lines, faces, volumes, spheres,...), via an API into a database.

Some values are unique for every entity, others are always the same.
So my idea was to do something like (SetValues is the API command i have to use putting something into the database):

```
def CreateLineEntity(ID,Name,Solver,P1,P2,Move='no',Perimeter=0.0,Gap='yes'): 
    SetValues(ID, {'Name':Name})
    SetValues(ID, {'P1':P1})
    SetValues(ID, {'P2':P2})
    SetValues(ID, {'Solver':Solver})
    SetValues(ID, {'Move':Move})
    SetValues(ID, {'Perim':Perimeter})
    SetValues(ID, {'Gap':Gap})
######################################################################
def CreatePointEntity(ID,Name,Solver,P1,Move='no',Perimeter=0.0,Gap='yes'): 
    SetValues(ID, {'Name':Name})
    SetValues(ID, {'P1':P1})
    SetValues(ID, {'Solver':Solver})
    SetValues(ID, {'Move':Move})
    SetValues(ID, {'Perim':Perimeter})
    SetValues(ID, {'Gap':Gap})
```

So in every function the default for Move is 'no'

If the default changes for some reason i had to check the complete code changing the default now.

Is there a more intelligent way to define such defaults?
My goal is to change only one value in the code and than all defaults in the functions are changed, too

Comment: How about defining a global variable `default_move` that is set to `'no'`, and in the functions you write `Move=default_move`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually keep a `constants.py` in all such projects.

Here:

**constant.py**

```
MOVE = 'no'
```

**yourFile.py**

```
from constants import MOVE  # add as many constants as needed
def CreateLineEntity(ID,Name,Solver,P1,P2,Move=MOVE,Perimeter=0.0,Gap='yes'): 
    SetValues(ID, {'Name':Name})
    SetValues(ID, {'P1':P1})
    SetValues(ID, {'P2':P2})
    SetValues(ID, {'Solver':Solver})
    SetValues(ID, {'Move':Move})
    SetValues(ID, {'Perim':Perimeter})
    SetValues(ID, {'Gap':Gap})
######################################################################
def CreatePointEntity(ID,Name,Solver,P1,Move=MOVE,Perimeter=0.0,Gap='yes'): 
    SetValues(ID, {'Name':Name})
    SetValues(ID, {'P1':P1})
    SetValues(ID, {'Solver':Solver})
    SetValues(ID, {'Move':Move})
    SetValues(ID, {'Perim':Perimeter})
    SetValues(ID, {'Gap':Gap})
```

In this case, hierarchy is as follows:

```
headFolder
    -constants.py
    -yourFile.py
```

Comment: Upvote as you do it the same way like me. Was currently writing my answer and didn't see yours yet ;P Anyway, I think this should be the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary for storing default values.

```
defaults = {"move": "no", "perimeter": 0.0, "gap":"yes"}

def CreatePointEntity(ID,Name,Solver,P1,Move=defaults["move"],Perimeter=defaults["perimeter"],Gap=defaults["gap"]): 
    SetValues(ID, {'Name':Name})
    SetValues(ID, {'P1':P1})
    SetValues(ID, {'Solver':Solver})
    SetValues(ID, {'Move':Move})
    SetValues(ID, {'Perim':Perimeter})
    SetValues(ID, {'Gap':Gap})
```

That way you need to only change default value inside the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

How about storing the default values in a separate file as Constants.

e.g:

constants.py:

```
MOVE = "on"
PERIMETER = "xyz"
...
```

Your script:

```
from constants import *

def CreateLineEntity(ID,Name,Solver,P1,P2,Move=MOVE,Perimeter=PERIMETER,Gap=GAP): 
    SetValues(ID, {'Name':Name})
    SetValues(ID, {'P1':P1})
    SetValues(ID, {'P2':P2})
    SetValues(ID, {'Solver':Solver})
    SetValues(ID, {'Move':Move})
    SetValues(ID, {'Perim':Perimeter})
    SetValues(ID, {'Gap':Gap})
######################################################################
def CreatePointEntity(ID,Name,Solver,P1,Move=MOVE,Perimeter=PERIMETER,Gap=GAP): 
    SetValues(ID, {'Name':Name})
    SetValues(ID, {'P1':P1})
    SetValues(ID, {'Solver':Solver})
    SetValues(ID, {'Move':Move})
    SetValues(ID, {'Perim':Perimeter})
    SetValues(ID, {'Gap':Gap})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change default value for `Move` argument in your methods, by using `func_defaults` tuple, which holds values from kwargs:

```
# CreateLineEntity.func_defaults --> ('no', 0.0, 'yes')
defaults = list(CreateLineEntity.func_defaults) 
# You're modyfying first one which is for ``Move``
defaults[0] = 'yes'
# And assign them back with changed value
CreateLineEntity.func_defaults = tuple(defaults)
```

Then running again the same function, `no` will be replaced by `yes` in this example.